# Setting the SWT Button to pressed state programmatically?

Tags: java, button, swt, state

I am trying to set a SWT Button into a "pressed" state programmatically.
Is that possible somehow?

**Update:** 
What I am trying to achieve - is render draw a Button in it's selected state onto an Image.

```
Image buttonimg_mouseover = new Image(getDisplay(), 100, 100);
Button button = new Button(parent.parent, SWT.PUSH);
button.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
button.setImage(arrowimg);
button.setSize(100, 100);
button.setSelection(true); // doesn't work

GC gcbutton = new GC(buttonimg_mouseover); //draw an image of the button
button.print(gcbutton);
```

Comment: Do you need to get it into the "pressed" state, or do you want to run the action that it is connected to?

Comment: I only want to render the button in pressed state, once - I do not want to trigger the associated methods.

Comment: Which style bits does the button have? `SWT.PUSH`, `SWT.CHECK`, `SWT.TOGGLE` or something else?

Comment: It does have a `SWT.PUSH` style

Comment: @Skip Are you sure, that you don't want a button with `SWT.TOGGLE`? See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/swt/swt-button-example/). Because the answer by @TomSeidel does only work with the styles `CHECK`, `RADIO`, or `TOGGLE`.

Comment: I update the Question, where I describe my intention

Comment: @Skip Then go for a `Button` with `SWT.TOGGLE` and use the answer of @TomSeidel to "push" the button. If necessary wait for some milliseconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with the following snippet

```
Button myButton = new Button(parent, SWT.TOGGLE);
myButton.setSelection(true);
```

However, this will only work with the types `CHECK`, `RADIO` or `TOGGLE`.

See Javadoc of [`Button#setSelection(boolean)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Button.html#setSelection%28boolean%29).

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, since this seem to set the app focus to this button, and setting focus to a button needs time. What I do is creating a Button, rendering it and then destroy the Button - no time to set selection on the Button.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by rendering and destroying buttons. Can you provide a bit more context, please?