# How to set checked a swt.CHECK in java

Tags: java

I have a

```
private Button testSomethingCheckBox;

testSomethingCheckBox= new Button(parent, SWT.CHECK);
```

I want it to be checked(Activated) when I call another function? Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the SWT Button to pressed state programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308066/setting-the-swt-button-to-pressed-state-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to read this [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html).
As for your question, use `testSomethingCheckBox.setSelection(true);` when you call the function you desire.

Comment: I had already used this option, but probably i have written something false, thank you anyway , problem solved.